# jQuery .innerWidth() giving different values in different browsers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, webkit, jquery-ui-slider

I'm trying to make an image gallery using the jQuery UI slider widget. My code requires me to find the inner width of an unordered list. In Firefox, IE and Opera I get a value of 2193px for this however in Chrome this value is 44px!

When I hardcode 2193px into the width of the UL it works fine in Chrome.

Here's a link to the code [Slider Test](http://www.takerootdesign.co.uk/example/slidertest/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be interested in this answer too... At times, I've found that the scripts can run before the images are loaded in the browser.  That causes the values to be different, as the widths aren't established yet.  Try putting the height and width in a style tag for each image, and see if that works.

Comment: Brilliant! Added height and width values to each image and it's sorted the problem out. Thank you!

Comment: Safari and Chrome (webkit) can fire the document onload event prematurely (before the page is done asynchronously loading images, among other things). So, you end up not knowing sizes for some images and their containers immediately after page load. You have to wait for image loads before the browser recalculates page flow. So mike's right about your script not knowing the sizes in time.